# autocomplete for people picker field is not working in infopath custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In my SharePoint 2013 environment, I have a custom list that has been customized with infopath 2013. I am using a multi-select people picker field. The auto populate no longer works the field after customizing in infoPath.  I have researched this issue and have not found a clear solution.  If someone has a clear solution can you please post with the exact steps on implementing a solution to this.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**InfoPath** controls behave differently than the **SharePoint** controls, **`InfoPath people  Picker`** resolve the typed user when clicking **`Check Names`** button, while **`SharePoint people picker`** resolves the typed user by the first typed letters, 
So infopath people picker does not provide OOTB SharePoint's people picker's autocomplete functionality.
I found here's a custom implementaion to this function, check this post to add [jQueryUI’s Autocomplete Function on InfoPath Forms](https://manojssharepointblog.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/jqueryuis-autocomplete-function-on-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint/) ,
  Hope this will help.